# label = np.where(df['Sentimen']=='Positif','Negatif','Netral' ,1, 0,-1) y = label y[45:75]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [32], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 label = np.where(df['Sentimen']=='Positif','Negatif','Netral' ,1, 0,-1)
      2 y = label
      3 y[45:75]

File <__array_function__ internals>:179, in where(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

When I use the last two lines of the code after creating all my classes,

```
TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `np.where`, it accepts either one argument, or three arguments. The first argument must be an array consisting of `True` or `False` (i.e. `bool` values). Optionally two additional arrays of the same shape/size can be passed.

You have passed `np.where` 6 arguments. The first is a conditional, `df['Sentimen']=='Positif'`, that's good. You have then passed it two strings and three integers. That is clearly contrary to what the function expects and can work with. Hence the error.

If you provide a fuller example/explanation of what you're trying to do, we could offer more specific help with solving your problem.

Best of luck.

Comment: can you give an example? I'm here to label analysis data from Twitter using jupyter notebooks. I did a positive neutral and negative sentiment analysis. I want to change the value of positive negative and neutral sentiment. Thank you

Comment: i use algorithm naive bayes and optimization with particle swarm optimization